# CAML Query to filter a list item based on comparing item["Title"] to ascx label.text control?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, asp.net, caml-renderpattern

```
     "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>'Label1.Text'</Value>    </Eq></Where>";
```

I have not run this and checked yet, simply because I am quite sure it is not going to work. 
How exactly do I specify the syntax to compare and filter a list item[title] to a label.text
Thanks

Comment: string query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Label1.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

Comment: @sssreddy you should post that as an answer... since it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do to make that query valid, is ensure the Label1.Text uses the actual value, rather than the text 'Label1.Text'

In C# it would be something like

```
String camlQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Label1.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: And make sure to Encode Label1.Text so it can't contain < and other chars which might leave you open for CAML injection attacks